# Telerik RadGrid_Itemdatabound

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid

I am trying to show the records fetched from database on gridview.But,I am not able to bind the fetched data with grid_itemdatabound.

After fetching the record from database,i am not able to go inside the if condition.It is happening like the part "e.Item is GridDataItem" in if condition is false.Any suggestions ??

Here is the .aspx code,where i am getting problem.

```
private void RadGrid_Itemdatabound(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
{

    if ((e.Item is GridDataItem)) 
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "SOME TEXT TO BE PRNTED";
    }
}
```

Comment: Does that event get hit and you just can't step in the if part?

Comment: Yes,event get hit and i am not able to step in if part.

Comment: Does the dataSet your binding have data in it? The code you have looks correct.

Comment: Yes,i am able to fetch the data from database and there is records in dataset.I dont know somehow e.Item is GridDataItem is coming false for me.

Answer (score 0):

`Itemdatabound` event includes other type of items too such as `GridHeaderItem`.

For example, if `e.Item` is `GridHeaderItem`, `e.Item is GridDataItem` will be false.

Besides, if you want to access a control inside item, you need to cast to appropriate control type.

For example,

```
private void RadGrid_Itemdatabound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Item is GridDataItem) 
   {
      var item = (GridDataItem) e.Item;
      var user= (User) e.Item.DataItem; // Cast to appropriate object
      var lblMessage = (Label) item.FindControl("lblMessage");
      lblMessage.Text = user.FirstName;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.But,i am not able to go inside that if condition part i.e e.item is GridDataItem is somehow false and after event being called i am just coming out of loop and no mesaage is populating on the grid.If i consider your example,i will not be able to get lblmessage.text part on my grid.

Comment: If there is no item in `DataSource`, you'll never reach inside if statement. Set a break point at `if (e.Item is GridDataItem)` and see type of `e.Item`.

Comment: Okay,i'll try out your suggestion and let u know.But,i am able to fetch the data from database and getting the counts of records fetched from database.